# Angular module needs to be defined twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been playing around with some angular code and I found that it has `app.controllers` twice on the page. Once in the module of app towards the top and once at the bottom. But when I remove one or the other the code breaks. I don't know why you need both since the `app.services` doesn't need that or the directives or filters. Any insights on why?

```
(function () {
  angular
    .module('app',
      [
        'app.controllers',
        'app.services',
        'app.directives',
        'app.filters'
      ]
    )
    .config(['$sceDelegateProvider','$routeProvider',
      function ($sceDelegateProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
           'self',
           'https://maps.google.com/**']);
        $routeProvider

          // Home
          .when('/',
            {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
            }
          )
        // Default
          .otherwise('/');
        }
      ]
    );
    angular.module('app.controllers', []);
}());
```

Comment: app.controllers is a separate module that gets imported into the main module at the top and then defined at the bottom. fancy if it works. also look at the end of the invoked function.. should be like this:

( function(){} )();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code :

```
.module('app', [
   'app.controllers',
   'app.services',
   'app.directives',
   'app.filters'
 ]);
```

is creating a new module named `app`. Inside `[]` you will find the list of dependencies modules. `app.controllers` is one of your app dependencie.

Whereas this code :

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []);
```

is creating a new module called `app.controllers` with no dependencies => `[]` (empty array).

---

### To summarize

1. To **create a new module**
   `angular.module('MODULE_NAME', []);` (Note there are `[]`)
2. To **access the module** previously created
   `angular.module('MODULE_NAME');`
3. Convention name **xx.yy** (like `app.controllers`) helps to know that the module **xx.yy** depends of **xx** (`app.controllers` is a dependency of `app`)

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but why don't app.filters, services, and directives need to have a new module created?

Comment: I assume they are defined in an another file ?! It's common to separate AngularJS modules in separate files

Comment: they do, it's just probably done at the top of their file rather than in this file, which makes it less obvious that it's happening.

Comment: Yep, I just foun them in their respective files. Thanks